# jquery fadetoggle is not working

Tags: jquery

Hello I am working with jquery and for some odd reason I cannot get fadetoggle to work.

I have Jquery 1.7.2, the correct src connection to the file on the folder (i can run other jquery events)

I have this in a body

```
<p id="rock"> hi </p>
<input type="button" class="joe"/>
```

and this in an external .js file sheet.

```
$('.joe').click(function(){
    $('#rock').fadeToggle('slow');  
});
```

Would anyone know what could possible be wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to work fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/ESbXr/

Comment: it should work as works here http://jsfiddle.net/rbh6X/ the problem is not the script, i believe jquery is not loaded correctly.

Comment: Lol, one more for good measure: http://jsfiddle.net/QLVTQ/

Comment: i also try to test it on jsfiddle.net and your code really works. could you show your .js file sheet? maybe you've encounter an error.

Comment: @JeffRobertDagala really? do you want to add the fourth fiddle?

Comment: @undefined 3 fiddle is enough to prove. :)

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

```
$('.joe').on('click',function(){ 
    $('#rock').fadeToggle('slow');
});
```